# Como mejorar mi paginador para que cargue los datos sin recargar la pantalla php y mysqli

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

ya tengo mi paginador terminado y mi consulta en php, todo funciona perfectamente pero quisiera mejorar mi paginador para que al momento de seleccionar otra pagina no recargue toda la pantalla, la idea seria pasar de pagina en pagina sin recargar la pantalla.

Se podria hacer con ajax? o con javascript? no se si me puedan ayudar o orientar de como hacerlo pero mejorando el codigo que ya tengo hecho.

Este es mi index.php

```
include('parametro_tiempo.php');

<h2>Tiempos</h2>
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col"></th>
                                    <th scope="col">FLOTA</th>
                                    <th scope="col">TIEMPO</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
<?php
            while($crowtmp = mysqli_fetch_array($tiempoquery)){

?>
                                <tr>                    
                                    <td><?php echo "<a href='elimitiemp.php?id_tiemp=".$crowtmp['id_tiemp']."' onclick='return ConfirmDelete()'><img src='imagenes/elim.png' width='30px'></a>";?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $crowtmp['flota_tiemp']; ?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $crowtmp['tiempo_progra']; ?></td>


                                </tr>
<?php
            }       
?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
    <div id="pagination_controls"><?php echo $paginationtiempo; ?></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
    </div>
```

y mi archivo parametro_tiempo.php alli esta el paginador.

```
<?php
    include("conn.php");

    $query=mysqli_query($conn,"select count(id_tiemp) from `para_tiempos`");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);

    $rows = $row[0];

    $page_rows = 10;

    $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);

    if($last < 1){
        $last = 1;
    }

    $pagenum = 1;

    if(isset($_GET['pntime'])){
        $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pntime']);
    }

    if ($pagenum < 1) { 
        $pagenum = 1; 
    } 
    else if ($pagenum > $last) { 
        $pagenum = $last; 
    }

    $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;

    $tiempoquery=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `para_tiempos` $limit");

    $paginationtiempo = '';

    if($last != 1){

    if ($pagenum > 1) {
        $previous = $pagenum - 1;
        $paginationtiempo .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pntime='.$previous.'" class="btn btn-default">Anterior</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';

        for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
            if($i > 0){
                $paginationtiempo .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pntime='.$i.'" class="btn btn-default">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
            }
        }
    }

    $paginationtiempo .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';

    for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){
        $paginationtiempo .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pntime='.$i.'" class="btn btn-default">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
        if($i >= $pagenum+4){
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($pagenum != $last) {
        $next = $pagenum + 1;
        $paginationtrabajo .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pntra='.$next.'" class="btn btn-default">Siguiente</a> ';
    }
    }

?>
```

Como les comente anteriormente todo mi código funciona correctamente, seria ver de que forma podria agregarle ajax o javascript para que al pasar a otra pagina no recargue la pagina.

Saludos y cualquier ayuda me seria de gran utilidad.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Espero que este tutorial te ayude: [Instant Search with Pagination in PHP Mysql jQuery and Ajax](https://www.webslesson.info/2020/02/instant-search-with-pagination-in-php-mysql-jquery-and-ajax.html), a mi me sirvió para hacer algo similar.

Tendrías que agregar Ajax, modificar tu control de paginación y generar la tabla en el archivo php que llame la función Ajax.

Comment: estupendo voy a revisar y ya te cuento como me fue, muchas gracias.